# How can i click button and change label text in tablewviewcell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uilabel

I want to change label text when i was click button in every TableViewCell

I mean have 2(-,+) button and 1 label, When I click on the button, the label will increase or decrease.

I have no idea 
How to do it?
[image: sample image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Post some code.

Comment: you can use library valuestepper 
to do that https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/valuestepper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to maintain a `quantityArray` to store current quantity of every index

```
var quantityArray:[Int] = [] //initialize quantity array
```

then add initial quantity values to `quantityArray` 
**For example : If your list array count 10 and initial quantity of all item will be one means**
add initial values to the array

```
for i in 0 ..< 10 {
   quantityArray.append(1)
}
```

then in your `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`

assign quantity value from quantityArray

```
cell.qtyLbl.text = "\(quantityArray[indexPath.row])"
cell.incrementBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.incrementBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.incrementBtnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
cell.decrementBtn.tag = indexPath.row
cell.decrementBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(self.decrementBtnClicked(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
```

add below functions into your `viewcontroller`

```
func incrementBtnClicked(_ sender:UIButton){
    let increasedQty = quantityArray[sender.tag]+1
    self.quantityArray.replaceSubrange(sender.tag, with: increasedQty)
    self.tableView.reloadData
}

func decrementBtnClicked(_ sender:UIButton){
    let decreasedQty = quantityArray[sender.tag]-1
    self.quantityArray.replaceSubrange(sender.tag, with: decreasedQty)
    self.tableView.reloadData
}
```

If you use like this even after scroll tableview also quantity in the cell will be populated from quantity array

Hope this will help you

Comment: let increasedQty = quantityArray[indexPath.row]-1    i getting error at indexpath.row

Comment: i change functions this way and worked  let azalt = Int(urunler.adet[sender.tag])!-1
        self.urunler.adet[sender.tag] = String(azalt)
        self.sepetimTableview.reloadData() .  thanks

Comment: @GaneshManickam its giving an error on sender.tag saying "expected Range<Int> found Int"

Comment: have you set the tag value for buttons? @Neck

Comment: @GaneshManickam Yes I have tagged them as you mentioned here. like: "itemCell.itemIncrementButton.tag = indexPath.section" and even tried with: "itemCell.itemIncrementButton.tag = indexPath.row"

Comment: Can you post that as separate question and tag my name in comment? @Neck

Comment: @GaneshManickam here is my question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50869215/how-to-update-uilabel-on-a-button-click-in-uitableviewcell-in-swift-4-and-xcode/50869263#50869263]

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is to add an action to your button and do your job.

```
@IBAction func increase() {
    quantityLabel.text = "\(quantity)" // increase the quantity number and set it
}
```

btw. before getting any help you should consider posting your code.